# Effect of accessibility levels on performance or speed?

Tags: c#, c++

I am just wondering that if making the methods (or parameters) private or public has any effect on the performance/speed of the overall application.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That means it is only for the security or design purpose, we use accessibility levels?

Comment: Only for design purposes, not for security (making a method private does not make it protected against attacks)

Comment: Purely for design. Translated into assembly / CLR Bytecode, there is no semblance of "access levels" that remains.

Comment: @LorenzoDematté: Can you elaborate on how can one attack on private member. I suppose on one can access that other than the class itself, in which it is declared. Thanks

Comment: @Yuushi: Oh, got your point. This probably answered my question to LorenzoDematte too. Thanks.

Comment: Making a member private does not "hide" it in any way; it is not obfuscated, or removed, or secured, or whatever. You can still access it quite easily, through reflection for example. Hence, there is no additional "security" in marking (for example) a string field containing a password as `private`

Comment: @Yuushi actually.. in .NET accessibility is retained in the IL (they are marked as `.method private`). Your point is still valid for C++ though!

Comment: Thanks @LorenzoDematté. Now that is more clear.

Comment: You are welcome. It was just a word of warning; I have seen people believe that a password is secure only because it is in a private filed. Don't fall in that trap!

Comment: Thanks @LorenzoDematté. Though I was not using it for protecting any password but yes, I dint know this fact so it saved me from doing any such kind of mistake in future.

Answer (score 1):

Just declaring a method private or public do not affect its speed or performance but it will affect the accessibility of the method,if you want to access the method from a different class or different package then its scope as public or private will change the scene.
for better understanding go through following links::
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/